# How to I get an LDAP Client to validate a LDAP instance?

Tags: ldap, testing

Try connecting with an LDAP client like [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) to validate that a LDAP instance is up an running at the host and port I think it is.

Also, trying to use any of the LDAP config data here:

- http://www.emailman.com/ldap/public.html

But need the LDAP client to return a record.

Here's an example URI:

- [ldap://ldap.itd.umich.edu/dc=umich,dc=edu??sub?uid=mcs](http://ldap://ldap.itd.umich.edu/dc=umich,dc=edu??sub?uid=mcs)
- **Host** ldap.itd.umich.edu **and path** dc=umich,dc=edu?uid,cn?sub?uid=mcs
- (Details on the meaning of that URI may be found [here](http://labs.watchmouse.com/2010/06/ldap_monitoring/))

**MORE_INFO:** Just ask, not 100% sure what info I need to give to get help - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your LDAP client caches data, simply connecting to your domain name and port (389 or 636 for Active Directory), and then browsing containers and objects will tell you that LDAP is running.

I use ADExplorer primarily, and sometimes Apache Directory Explorer, and basically just connecting is enough to say that LDAP service is being provided...

Also running any query tool or script will validate for you.  A few lines of Perl using Net::LDAP will validate you as well...

Please feel free to let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: **@gWaldo:** "Authentication with the LDAP server succeeded." -- You have no idea how happy those words made me... :-) ...thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I was about to put together a short perl script that just binds to LDAP, which is enough to tell you that it's working...